# Minimum credential for WMI parameters Monitoring?

Tags: c#, security, wmi, remote-access

I'm developing a big project to monitor a remote machine's performance parameters like CPU,Memory,Diskspace through C# WMI. I want to use the minimum possible credentials to connect the remote machines. Because I don't want to bother my client to ask for the super-user credentials. Its sure that if I disabled the firewall and use the super user credentials, WMI is fine; but resource monitoring in such environment means giving lots of space to the system intrusion for the hacker. So, my main question is what is the minimum system vulnerabilities that we can expose for the remote machine for such monitoring?

Comment: Are you wanting to allow remote monitoring of a system over the Internet or on the local network?

Comment: I need the remote access independent of the connectivity. It should not matter if the machine is in LAN or in cloud or somewhere else.

Comment: Sure it just helps to identify what vulnerability you might have to protect against. Also is there a reason why an out-of-the-box solution like System Center Operations Manager (SCOM) http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/system-center/operations-manager.aspx is not a good option? It can be extended for almost any task.

Comment: This type of question may be better answered on the IT Security part of Stack Exchange (http://security.stackexchange.com/) if you are looking for general security design advise.

Comment: Thanx Bernie, I'll post this question in security.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is to setup a domain user account that have WMI access and all, set it up in the Active Directory (This includes pushing updated firewall rules to all machines etc, enable your user for WMI monotoring on the machines). Typically this user can't do anything else, not perform a local logon etc.

Then in your code just do Impersonation with that user.